# Linq Sort IEnumerable on multiple tiers

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, sorting

I am writing a simple test app to show how to sort an list that I will get from an EF Context.

The "goal" is to get a list, sorted by Student.Name, then Subject.Name

```
public class Student
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public List<ExamScore> ExamScores{get;set;}
}

public class Subject
{
    public string Name{get;set;}
}

public class ExamScore
{
    public Subject Subject{get;set;}
    public int Score{get;set;}
}
```

The first level sorting is easy:

```
var list = con.Students
    .Include(e => e.ExamScores
        .Select(s => s.Subjects))
    .OrderBy(x => x.Name) //student.Name
    .ToList();
```

But adding the next level is confusing me.

```
var list = con.Students
    .Include(e => e.ExamScores
        .Select(s => s.Subjects))
    .OrderBy(x => x.Name) //student.Name
    .ThenBy(y => y.ExamScores.???) //subject name???
    .ToList();
```

**Input**

```
Student{"Jannie", ExamScore{ Subject{"Math"}, 90}}
Student{"Jannie", ExamScore{ Subject{"History"}, 70}}
Student{"Jannie", ExamScore{ Subject{"Science"}, 90}}

Student{"Koos", ExamScore{ Subject{"Xhosa"}, 83}}
Student{"Koos", ExamScore{ Subject{"Afrikaans"}, 74}}
Student{"Koos", ExamScore{ Subject{"English"}, 78}}

Student{"Pieter", ExamScore{ Subject{"Afrikaans"}, 65}}
Student{"Pieter", ExamScore{ Subject{"History"}, 80}}
Student{"Pieter", ExamScore{ Subject{"Math"}, 70}}

Student{"Sannie", ExamScore{ Subject{"Science"}, 60}}
Student{"Sannie", ExamScore{ Subject{"Math"}, 55}}
Student{"Sannie", ExamScore{ Subject{"Biology"}, 75}}

Student{"Magriet", ExamScore{ Subject{"Biology"}, 75}}
Student{"Magriet", ExamScore{ Subject{"English"}, 80}}
Student{"Magriet", ExamScore{ Subject{"Science"}, 90}}
```

**Expected output**

```
Student{"Jannie", ExamScore{ Subject{"History"}, 70}}
Student{"Jannie", ExamScore{ Subject{"Math"}, 90}}
Student{"Jannie", ExamScore{ Subject{"Science"}, 90}}

Student{"Koos", ExamScore{ Subject{"Afrikaans"}, 74}}
Student{"Koos", ExamScore{ Subject{"English"}, 78}}
Student{"Koos", ExamScore{ Subject{"Xhosa"}, 83}}

Student{"Magriet", ExamScore{ Subject{"Biology"}, 75}}
Student{"Magriet", ExamScore{ Subject{"English"}, 80}}
Student{"Magriet", ExamScore{ Subject{"Science"}, 90}}

Student{"Pieter", ExamScore{ Subject{"Afrikaans"}, 65}}
Student{"Pieter", ExamScore{ Subject{"History"}, 80}}
Student{"Pieter", ExamScore{ Subject{"Math"}, 70}}

Student{"Sannie", ExamScore{ Subject{"Biology"}, 75}}
Student{"Sannie", ExamScore{ Subject{"Math"}, 55}}
Student{"Sannie", ExamScore{ Subject{"Science"}, 60}}
```

Comment: Could you give an example of the expected output?

Comment: The collection of students *contains* the collection of subjects, so it's not possible to filter the student collection based on the score

Comment: @bit It has been done.

Comment: @GertArnold thanks, I fixed it. It must be of type Subject.

Comment: @AlexanderDerck Student does not contain Subject. I think you misread.

Comment: @AtronSeige I mean student contains score which contains a single subject, so indirectly it does. The only option is to flatten out the list as Dmitri said in his answer.

Comment: Can you try this *.ThenBy(y => y.ExamScores.OrderBy(es => es.Subject.Name))*

Comment: @bit it throws "At least one object must implement IComparable."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you need to do is first flatten the Student->Subject relation and then you will be able sort on both:

```
var list = con.Students.Include(e => e.ExamScores.Select(s => s.Subjects))
    .SelectMany(student => student.ExamScores.Select(score => new { Student = student, Score = score }))
    .OrderBy(x => x.Student.Name)
    .ThenBy(x => x.Score.Subject.Name);
```

This will produce an enumerable of anonymous objects which contain both Student and Score sorted by student name and subject name.

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.SelectMany()` as Dmitri suggests. Here's a compilable working example to illustrate his answer (I was working on this while he answered, so I didn't want to waste it, but his is the correct answer and I have of course upvoted it):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Demo
{
    public class Student
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<ExamScore> ExamScores { get; set; }
    }

    public class Subject
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class ExamScore
    {
        public Subject Subject 
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public int Score { get; set; }
    }

    static class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var students = new List<Student>
            {
                new Student
                {
                    Name = "C",
                    ExamScores = new List<ExamScore>
                    {
                        new ExamScore {Subject = new Subject {Name = "Z"}, Score = 1},
                        new ExamScore {Subject = new Subject {Name = "Y"}, Score = 2},
                        new ExamScore {Subject = new Subject {Name = "X"}, Score = 3},
                    }
                },

                new Student
                {
                    Name = "B",
                    ExamScores = new List<ExamScore>
                    {
                        new ExamScore {Subject = new Subject {Name = "Z"}, Score = 4},
                        new ExamScore {Subject = new Subject {Name = "Y"}, Score = 5},
                        new ExamScore {Subject = new Subject {Name = "X"}, Score = 6},
                    }
                },

                new Student
                {
                    Name = "A",
                    ExamScores = new List<ExamScore>
                    {
                        new ExamScore {Subject = new Subject {Name = "Z"}, Score = 7},
                        new ExamScore {Subject = new Subject {Name = "Y"}, Score = 8},
                        new ExamScore {Subject = new Subject {Name = "X"}, Score = 9},
                    }
                }
            };

            var orderedStudents = 
                students.SelectMany(s => s.ExamScores.Select(e => new {Student = s, ExamScore = e}))
                .OrderBy(x => x.Student.Name)
                .ThenBy(x => x.ExamScore.Subject.Name);

            foreach (var item in orderedStudents)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{item.Student.Name} {item.ExamScore.Subject.Name} {item.ExamScore.Score}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The only difference I can see is that ".Include(x => x.ExamScores.Select(s => s.Subject))" is removed from your example. The answers seem identical otherwise. Is that correct.

Comment: please explain the " Console.WriteLine($"{item.Student.Name}..." part. this does not compile on my side.

Comment: @AtronSeige That's a C# 6 feature (Visual Studio 2015). For earlier versions, use `Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", item.Student.Name, item.ExamScore.Subject.Name, item.ExamScore.Score);`.

Comment: @AtronSeige Actually, it's pretty much identical, so Dmitri's reply should be marked as the answer. I was working on this while he answered, and I didn't want to waste this answer since it contains a compilable example.

Comment: Thanks. for the explanation. Will mark Dmitri's as the answer. Cheers